# Android Periodic Job Scheduler Stops Running After 10-12 hrs or so

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am setting up a Periodic Job using the JobScheduler API from JetPack/Androidx. I schedule it to run every 15 minutes, with the only constraint being when the device is connected to any network.

The Job gets scheduled and run quite a few times within the window of 10-12 hrs. When the device is in doze or sleep mode, the frequency of how often the job runs changes but this is fine. When the device wakes up again, the job gets runs more frequently - so far so good.

Now, after 10-12 hrs, the job does not get run at all, even if I keep the device/screen on for some time. If I lookup the periodic job status (via WorkInfo), it's returned as ENQUEUED. But its never run.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Edit: I have during certain runs of the Job (when it gets scheduled) gets some exceptions (we bring the server down intentionally to test some scenarios). So there are exceptions like SocketException when the app could not connect to server. But all of these Exceptions are caught, and response is always `Result.success();`. Not sure, if the Job Scheduler knows that that was some exception thrown (although caught with the `doWork` function), and automatically backs off the Job?

Comment: have you checked if system forced your app into lower [app standy bucket](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/appstandby)?

Comment: When the app gets setup, I have ask the user to allow ignoreBatteryOptimiation. So the app is not being battery optimized. And in the developer options, I can see that my app is exempted from these buckets (I believe this is due to the not being battery optimized).